# Displaying CollectionView as InfiniteView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

Is there a way to display CollectionView as if its an infinite view going in both directions in Xamarin Forms?

like android number picker does, where going up brings you back to the end of the list and going down to the bottom.

If scrolling towards the bottom Im just loading the list with content from the top which works great but going towards the top is the issue.

I tried hacking at it for a little while now and was trying to search for a previously asked post but no luck...

Comment: check CarouselView

Comment: I did and when you show multiple items using the PeekAreaInsets property its doesnt really fit the way I intend and anyway when you are centered at the first item it doesnt show the items at the end of the list on top of it just empty space, I guess since it considers the center item to be the "first" rather then the one at the top of the list it just doesnt work as well...